# "By" or "with" in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

> I'm happy enough with hugging you like this!

Is it better if use "by" instead of "with" in this sentence? Is there another word that would be even better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Happy by something” isn't an English idiom.

The following two sentences are valid English:

> I'm happy enough **with hugging** you like this.
>   I'm happy enough **to hug** you like this.

They are almost, but not exactly synonymous. I'm having a hard time explaining the nuance. *Happy to* tends to mean that the hugging procures joy to the person, while *happy with* tends to mean that the person is satisfied with the hugging, but I think it's a little more subtle than that.

> Would you like a hug? I'd be happy to give you a hug.
>   I'm glad for the opportunity to hug you. I'm happy to hug you like this.
>   We've been hugging for a while, and I like it. I'm happy with hugging you like this.
>   — Shall we hug, or do you want to do more? — I'm happy with hugging you.

Answer (score 1):

I think "by" doesn't pass there but "to" is better.

Example:

> - I'm happy enough to hug you like this!

In my opinion "with" is correct but I think that "to" is better.

Comment: Why is *to* better? My (non-native's) impression is that they have slightly different meanings.

Comment: @Gilles My impression as a native speaker is the same as yours, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Going with @Gilles's nuance:

> I'm happy enough **to hug** you like this.

suggests your feelings *before* hugging and

> I'm happy enough **with hugging** you like this.

your feelings *during* the act of hugging.

One could consider that there is a difference in [aspect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperfective_aspect)- **to hug** being *perfective* and **with hugging** being *imperfective*.  If your native language uses these constructs (which English doesn't), it may be a clearer explanation.

Just my interpretation.